# Laravel5 make:auth doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel

I used the command make:auth and it showed:

```
Created View: /var/www/myblog/resources/views/auth/login.blade.php
Created View: /var/www/myblog/resources/views/auth/register.blade.php
Created View: /var/www/myblog/resources/views/auth/passwords/email.blade.php
Created View: /var/www/myblog/resources/views/auth/passwords/reset.blade.php
Created View: /var/www/myblog/resources/views/auth/emails/password.blade.php
Created View: /var/www/myblog/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php
Created View: /var/www/myblog/resources/views/home.blade.php
Created View: /var/www/myblog/resources/views/welcome.blade.php
Installed HomeController.
Updated Routes File.
Authentication scaffolding generated successfully!
```

It looks like great and I got a homepage showing up correctly. 
[see picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kn8tW.png)

But when I was trying to access Login and Register page, something went wrong.
It gave me errors like:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /login was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at ...
```

and I typed php artisan route:list in terminal I got this:

```
+--------+-----------+-------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                     | Name            | Action                                                          | Middleware |
+--------+-----------+-------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                       |                 | Closure                                                         |            |
|        | GET|HEAD  | article                 | article.index   | App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@index                    |            |
|        | POST      | article                 | article.store   | App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@store                    |            |
|        | GET|HEAD  | article/create          | article.create  | App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@create                   |            |
|        | DELETE    | article/{article}       | article.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@destroy                  |            |
|        | PUT|PATCH | article/{article}       | article.update  | App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@update                   |            |
|        | GET|HEAD  | article/{article}       | article.show    | App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@show                     |            |
|        | GET|HEAD  | article/{article}/edit  | article.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@edit                     |            |
|        | GET|HEAD  | home                    |                 | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                       | web,auth   |
|        | GET|HEAD  | login                   |                 | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm          | web,guest  |
|        | POST      | login                   |                 | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@login                  | web,guest  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | logout                  |                 | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@logout                 | web        |
|        | POST      | password/email          |                 | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail | web,guest  |
|        | POST      | password/reset          |                 | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@reset              | web,guest  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset/{token?} |                 | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm      | web,guest  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | register                |                 | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm   | web,guest  |
|        | POST      | register                |                 | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@register               | web,guest  |
+--------+-----------+-------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

It's a bit different from what I expect. Cuz from what I learned in laracast.com, the route list should be like "Auth\login" instead of merely "login"... Idk what's going wrong here, is it because I'm using apache? or other configurations I didn't set up correctly... Looking for help

Also another question:
when I access www.mydomain.com, I'd expect the default welcome page instead of auth's home page but actually it gives me the auth's home page instead. But when I was trying to access www.mydomain.com/home which I expect to see that home page again, instead I received 404 not found errors which confused me a lot. here is my routes.php:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Routes File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you will register all of the routes in an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This route group applies the "web" middleware group to every route
| it contains. The "web" middleware group is defined in your HTTP
| kernel and includes session state, CSRF protection, and more.
|
*/

Route::resource('article', 'ArticleController');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Guys I just solved this problem.

This problem is definitely unrelated to laravel and is totally caused by Apache2 settings.

What I did is simply 
sudo a2enmod rewrite
and restart service.